# Return key with highest value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following graph:

```
graph = {0 : {5:6, 4:8},
1 : {4:11},
2 : {3: 9, 0:12},
3 : {},
4 : {5:3},
5 : {2: 7, 3:4}}
```

I am trying to return the key that has the highest value in this graph. The expected output in this case would be 2 as key 2 has the highest value of 12.

Any help on how I can achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This needs a recursive solution. Think for the simple case such as graph={a:1,b:2} and then go for increasing dimensions.

Answer (score 7):

Find the key whose maximum value is maximal:

```
max((k for k in graph), key=lambda k: max(graph[k].values(), default=float("-inf")))
```

The empty elements are disqualified by the ridiculous maximum. Alternately, you can just pre-filter such keys:

```
max((k for k in graph if graph[k]), key=lambda k: max(graph[k].values()))
```

Comment: @ Amadan , can't it be a `max(mydict, key=mydict.get)`

Comment: @pygo: For inner or outer `max`? Both are a no: for inner, it would produce the maximum index, which I fail to find a use for; for the outer, it would compare the inner dicts, which is not a supported operation.

Comment: correct i see its `not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming it's all positive numbers

```
graph = {0 : {5:6, 4:8},
         1 : {4:11},
         2 : {3: 9, 0:12},
         3 : {},
         4 : {5:3},
         5 : {2: 7, 3:4}}

highestKey = 0
max = 0

for key, value in graph.items():
    for key2, value2 in value.items():
        if (max < value2):
            max = value2
            highestKey = key

print(highestKey)
```

Comment: This prints the value (`12`) when OP is asking for the key where it is found (`2`).

Answer (score 1):

You can also create `(max_weight, key)` tuples for each key and get the max of those:

```
max_val = max((max(e.values()), k) for k, e in graph.items() if e)
# (12, 2)

print(max_val[1])
# 2
```

Note that we don't need a custom `key` function for `max` here because the first value in the tuple is the one we want `max` to consider.

Answer (score 0):

The recursive solution is below. Does not make assumptions about depth of your tree. Only assumes that data types are either int, float or dict

```
import type 

def getLargest(d):
    def getLargestRecursive(d):    
        if type(d) == “dict”:
            getLargestRecursive(d)
        elif not largest or d > largest:
              largest = d
    largest = None
    getLargestRecursive(d)
    return largest


largestValues = [getLargest(k) for k in graph.keys]

answer = largestValues.index(max(largestValues))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use dict comprehension to flat the dictionary and then print the max `key`,

```
graph = {0 : {5:6, 4:8},
         1 : {4:11},
         2 : {3: 9, 0:12},
         3 : {},
         4 : {5:3},
         5 : {2: 7, 3:4}}

flat_dcit = {k:a for k, v in graph.items() for a in v.values()}
print(max(flat_dcit.keys(), key=(lambda k: flat_dcit[k])))

# output,
2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try flattening your dictionary into a list of tuples then take the max of the tuple with the highest second value:

```
from operator import itemgetter

graph = {
    0: {5: 6, 4: 8},
    1: {4: 11},
    2: {3: 9, 0: 12},
    3: {},
    4: {5: 3},
    5: {2: 7, 3: 4},
}

result = max(((k, v) for k in graph for v in graph[k].values()), key=itemgetter(1))

print(result)
# (2, 12)

print(result[0])
# 2
```